# Simple form inside dynamic Boostrap modal not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, simple-form, will-paginate

I have a table of links each opening a bootstrap modal containing a simple form.

I am using pagination to load more links onto my page. But the simple forms inside the new modals that got loaded (thru pagination) will submit.

Any ideas?

Some clues:

- If I paginate the simple forms without being placing them inside the modals, the forms submit properly and work.
- The forms inside the modals on the first page also work. Just not after I load more using pagination.

Index.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="results" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <%= render :partial => 'companies/list', :param_name => 'companies_page', :locals => { :companies => @companies } %> 
   </div>
</div>
```

_list.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <% @companies.each do |company| %>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
          <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#company_app_<%=company.id %>" onclick="">
            Interested
          </span>
        </td>
        <div class="modal" id="company_app_<%=company.id%>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="company_app_<%=company.id%>Label">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <%= simple_form_for(@company_candidate, :method => :post, url: { :controller=>"company_candidate", :action=>"create"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
                <%= f.submit "Apply", :class => "btn btn-primary", :onclick => "" %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<center>
  <%= js_will_paginate @companies, :param_name => 'companies_page', :params => { :public_id => session[:public_id] }, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</center>
```

Comment: Please post minimal code that can help us try to solve your issue.

Comment: @ArunKumar I have added some code to show what i am doing, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. Its because the modal wasn't inside the , the modal would work but the form wouldn't because of that.